# Using ROUND in IF in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I am using Numbers to track changes of time. I am using an `IF()` to show an upwards / downwards trend and there is an if that checks if there was any change at all. But I the calculation seems to be a bit *too* accurate for my taste.

```
IF(D11=D10;"=";IF(D11>D10;("⬆" & D11−D10);("⬇" & D11−D10)))
```

The top-level `IF()` detects whether the compared values are identical, to show an `=`. Otherwise, another `IF()` is used to check whether the new value is bigger than the old one, to show `⬆` with the amount of change, or `⬇`.

In one case, the calculation refers to cells that both *show* `65m` (minutes; from an `AVG()` referring to other cells), yet it shows a downward arrow with a change of `0m` in it:

[image: focused cell showing a red downward arrow with -0m, with two identical values highlighted from the formular]

Because the original cell format is all in time, I think that the calculation detects a change of seconds, but I actually don't show seconds here. So I've been trying to get `ROUND` to work on `D11` and `D10` for the first `IF()`, but honestly I am not sure what the syntax is here and I couldn't get it to work.

What I am trying to achieve is to show an `=` when the change is zero.

Comment: So what are you struggling with? The syntax of how to use ROUND() within an IF() or the right way to round the numbers to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

To round a number, you need to specify both the number to round, and how many places to round to.   So a simple rounding would look like

```
ROUND(D11,0)
```

For your formula, you can include rounding like so:

```
IF(ROUND(D10,0)=ROUND(D11,0),"=")
```

The rest of your formula looks fine, I just modified that first IF statement to handle the rounding.  If you need additional clarification just ask.

Answer (score 1):

The IF() formula in your post looks OK. So, I agree that the problem you describe could be caused by the durations being compared not being the same beyond the number of minutes and rounding them might be useful.

However, it is not possible to use ROUND() on a [duration value](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/types-of-arguments-and-values-ffaa26436a8c/web) such as `65m` in Numbers. This is most probably the gist of your problem rather than how you have been trying to use ROUND() and IF() together.

In Numbers, to round a duration value to minutes for example, first convert it to a decimal using [DUR2MINUTES()](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/dur2minutes-ffa56312b2/12.1/web/1.0) which converts a duration value to minutes in decimal. Then, round that to the closest integer using ROUND(). You can either convert the outcome back to a duration value with [DURATION()](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/duration-ffa561e8c4/web) or modify the IF() adding an `m` after each `D11 - D10` to get the output format in your post.

Here is the screenshot of an example spreadsheet using formulas incorporating these suggestions. I used AVERAGE() in the formulas only because you mentioned using it in calculating the cells in column D of your spreadsheet. I also pasted the formula at the top in the screenshot as text for your convenience after that:

[image: screenshot of example spreadsheet rounding durations in Numbers]

```
=DURATION(,,,ROUND(DUR2MINUTES(AVERAGE(A2:B2)),0))
```

If you are not using the cells in column D in your spreadsheet for anything else, you can just use the formulation above to calculate them and not need make any changes to the IF() in your post. If that is not possible, you can either add a column next to column D that would have the duration values in column D rounded as described above and then use those in the IF() or do the rounds within the IF() itself. The very last option, however, may result in an IF() which is a bit too long and hard to maintain.

Note that ROUND() will round, for example, both 1.98 (from 1 minutes and 59 seconds) and 2.03 (from 2 minutes and 2 second) to 2. If you wish those not to be considered as equal, then you can use ROUNDDOWN() or ROUNDUP().